# Rendering HTML inside a HTML,MYSQL,PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

Let suppose we've database table `my_code`

### Input

I'll create connection to this database table
I'll create form with post action
I'll create inside this form a textarea where i would write the input

[image: This is example]

### I want

To add HTML code inside this textarea to be saved in database table `my_code`
then i can get the HTML code applied in output page.

### Output Problem

If i put the following code inside the textarea after i replaced `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`

[image: This is example]

Now the output when i can it from database table `my_code` will appears as code

[image: This is example]

While i want it appears normally as visual HTML (applied) as following

[image: This is example]

Note : someone said rather than rendering html code in the input text just put it as it < and > and yes it would appears in output just as i want but when i try to edit it in edit page will find a huge distortion where it become active as textarea inside textarea so i must rendering it but in same time i want it appears as i want.

This problems hurts me so much so any idea,keywords or solutions for it please give help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note : someone said rather than rendering html code in the input text just put it as it < and > and yes it would appears in output just as i want but when i try to edit it in edit page will find a huge distortion where it become active as textarea inside textarea so i must rendering it but in same time i want it appears as i want.

Yes. Then only apply the HTML escaping ([`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)) when you want to edit your content.

If you want to output it as raw HTML (meaning it becomes a functional `<textarea>+text`), then *do not* apply said HTML escaping.

You cannot use the same htmlescaped data for both purposes. You have to apply it *depending* on what you want to do with it, and best only right before you do so.

Comment: Fine, I understood your idea and by using htmlspecialchars for example 

<?php 
$new = htmlspecialchars("<a href='test'>Test</a>", ENT_QUOTES); 
echo $new; // &lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt;
?>

Now is there any thing that can convert 
&lt;a href=&#039;test&#039;&gt;Test&lt;/a&gt; 
back to
<a href='test'>Test</a>

Comment: Found, I get it back using htmlspecialchars_decode , Thanks a lot now i will read about htmlspecialchars,htmlspecialchars_decode and also htmlentities and sure i would find solution for my problem. thanks a lot